# regex to extract HTML attribute value

Tags: html, regex, jmeter

I have the following HTML

```
<tr><td class="width35pct alignR"><span style="font-weight: bold;">TO :</span></td><td class="width40pct alignC"><input id="form:firstTON" name="form:firstTON" type="text" value="114" maxlength="17" tabindex="7" style="width:198px; margin: 5px 0 5px 0;" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" /><script id="form:firstTON_s" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[PrimeFaces.cw('InputText','widget_form_firstTON',{id:'form:firstTON'});//]]><![CDATA[]]]]><![CDATA[></script></td><td class="alignl"><span style="font-weight: bold !important;" class="ar">number</span></td></tr>
```

And i need to create a regex that extract the value "114" which is the value of "value" attribute.

Any help please ?

Comment: What **language** are you using?

Comment: am using Jmeter and i need to drive this value from the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JMeter, use [**Regular Expression Extractor**](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to achieve this task.

```
Reference Name: mynum
Regular Expression: value="(.+?)"
Template: $1$
Match No.: 1
```

If you specify using a `Match No:`, the rules are as follows:

```
0 = Random Match
1 = First Match 
2 = Second Match
etc....
```

And then you can use the corresponding variable to access the match. `${mynum_1}`