# How do I get values of parameters of an attribute of an element?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an element say:

```
<button id="buttonId" class="someClass anotherClass" onclick="javascript:somefunction('param1', 'param2')">
</button>
```

What I want is a way to get the values 'param1' and 'param2'. Is there any way I can get this with only javascript (not jQuery)?

I obtain the value with:

```
var value = document.getElementById('buttonId').getAttribute('onclick');
```

Comment: do you want the value by using selector or calling somefunction?

Comment: @Atiq I want the value by selector

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex to extract HTML attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404889/regex-to-extract-html-attribute-value)

Comment: Why do you have a label called `javascript:` in your JavaScript code?

Comment: @melpomene The function I am trying to get the values from currently was named like so on a website.

Comment: @LanceToth I am trying to get the parameter values of an attribute and not the attribute value itstelf

Comment: Question totally irrelevent to title, title is about html attribute, but the questioin is really about regex of `javascript:somefunction('param1', 'param2')`

Comment: @MunimMunna I thought there maybe a javascript function that may get me the parameters without the use of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var value = document.getElementById('buttonId').getAttribute('onclick');
console.log(value.split(/\(|\)/g)[1].split(/,\s*/g));
```

```html
<button id="buttonId" class="someClass anotherClass" onclick="javascript:somefunction('param1', 'param2', 'param3')">Click
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. May be easy to understand

```js
var attr =  document.getElementById("buttonId").getAttribute("onclick")  
console.log(attr.split("(")[1].split(")")[0].split(",").map(function (el) {
  return el.trim();
}))
```

```html
<button id="buttonId" class="someClass anotherClass" onclick="javascript:somefunction('param1', 'param2', 'param3')">Click
</button>
```

Comment: check your output. there is a space before param2 & param3

Answer (score 0):

Let's implement a function which is aware of its parameters:

```
function wrapper() {
    //Here I am logging it to the console, but one can do virtually anything with arguments
    console.log(arguments);
    //If you want to execute somefunction, then uncomment the next line
    //somefunction.call(arguments);
}
```

and now let's make sure you are calling `wrapper` instead of `somefunction`:

```
eval(button.attributes['onclick'].value.substring(11).replace('somefunction', 'wrapper'));
```