# How to extract the element from the response header using Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have the response header like 

   
      123456-4568-4f76-a9c7-123456789
   
How can I get the SOATransactionID element in the final result file what we get after the test run.

I have used the expression like SOATransactionID=(.*?)" in the regular expression path.But its not working

SOATransactionID=(.*?)"

I want that SOATransactionID to be present in the result file.
I have made changes to the user.properties, and already added SOATransactionID in the sample variables

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><cor:SOATransactionID xmlns:cor="http:/soa/coredata_1_0">26850477-9a89-4fe5-969b-4e5d5b9ca4f1</cor:SOATransactionID></soapenv:Header>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex to extract HTML attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404889/regex-to-extract-html-attribute-value)

Answer (score 1):

This `26850477-9a89-4fe5-969b-4e5d5b9ca4f1` structure looks like a [GUID](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier) therefore you can extract this like:

```
([0-9A-Fa-f]{8}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{12})
```

Demo:

[image]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: It wont work.Could you please help me how can I extract a id in my SOAP header using regex extractor

Comment: C'mon, it does work as it evidenced by the above screenshot, I cannot help further without seeing your response details and Regular Expression Extractor configuration.